# Multiple HTTP requests over socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, http, tcp

I want to HTTP GET the server ,read the data and then again do HTTP GET or POST over same socket connection. 
However I am unable to get a response for second request.What can be wrong with following code :

```
                Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("xyz.abc.asd"), 80);

            InputStream is=s.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os=s.getOutputStream();

            PrintWriter pwGET = new PrintWriter(os);

            pwGET.println("GET /login/ HTTP/1.1");
            pwGET.println("Host: xyz.abc.asd");
            pwGET.println("Connection: keep-alive");
            pwGET.println("");
            pwGET.flush();

            BufferedReader brGET = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


            String t=null;

            while((t = brGET.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(t);


            }

            pwGET.println("GET /login/ HTTP/1.1");
            pwGET.println("Host: xyz.abc.asd");
            pwGET.println("Connection: keep-alive");
            pwGET.println("");
            pwGET.flush();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


            t=null;

            while((t = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(t);


            }
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are successfully exiting that while loop to even make the second request?

Comment: Yes.I can read and print the response of first request successfully. Exit the while loop and execute some prints after words. However I can not read/get anything in second request.

Answer (score 2):

The main error is, that you don't parse the response correctly.
The response consists of an HTTP header followed by the body (maybe). To get the body you must parse and understand the response header, especially the code (some codes don't have a body), Transfer-Encoding and Content-length. Then you should also have a look at the Connection header.
Only then you know the length of the body and if further requests are accepted on this connection.

Apart from that lines should be delimited by \r\n, not just \n as you do with println.

In summary: if you really want to implement HTTP on your own study the necessary documentation (RFC2616 or the newer RFC7230..RFC7235). If you don't like this use existing HTTP libraries.

Comment: Specifically, read [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) or [RFC 7230 Section 3.3.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3), which both explain how to determine the length of the message body.